# Increase sleep interval for LED sequence whenever button is pressed. (Python)

Tags: led, python-3, gpiozero

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from time import sleep
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from threading import Thread
from signal import pause, signal, SIGTERM

LEDs = [5, 17, 22, 19, 26]
LIGHTS = [LED(LEDs[0]), LED(LEDs[1]), LED(LEDs[2]), LED(LEDs[3]), LED(LEDs[4])]
pushButton = Button(21)
DELAY = 0.5

def cleanup(signum, frame):
    exit(2)


# TODO: Create a button callback function which will change blinking speed
def buttonLEDs():
    global DELAY
    while True:
        if pushButton.is_pressed:
            print("Click")
            DELAY += 0.1


def LEDseq():
    while True:
        for LED in LIGHTS:
            LED.on()
            sleep(DELAY)
            LED.off()
        for LED in reversed(LIGHTS):
            LED.on()
            sleep(DELAY)
            LED.off()


try:
    signal(SIGTERM, cleanup)
    # pushButton = buttonControl
    # pushButton.when_pressed = LEDseq
    LEDseq()
    # buttonControl(LEDseq)
    pause()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit(1)
```

I'm trying to make a callback function for a button that would change the sleep interval of `LEDseq` when the button is pressed so I created this function:

but it doesn't seem to work. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to add your full code. Add a print statement inside your 'if .. is_pressed'

Comment: @CoderMike I added the `print` inside the if ... is_pressed as I also updated my question with a full. Check it out. And thank you for your response

Comment: That should be print('Click'). Does not look as though your code will even run - there is no flashLED()?

Comment: @CoderMike I've edited the code and still, the button won't work when I press it the LEDs still at the same sequence speed. And sorry for `flashLED()` that was supposed to be LEDseq that I've forgotten to rename

Comment: @CoderMike I also updated the code in the thread with the correction that you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will always be stuck inside the LEDseq() while loop.

Try the following, using the button when_pressed callback:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from time import sleep
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from threading import Thread
from signal import pause, signal, SIGTERM

LEDs = [5, 17, 22, 19, 26]
LIGHTS = [LED(LEDs[0]), LED(LEDs[1]), LED(LEDs[2]), LED(LEDs[3]), LED(LEDs[4])]
pushButton = Button(21)
DELAY = 0.5

def cleanup(signum, frame):
    exit(2)

def incrementDelay():
    global DELAY
    print("Click")
    DELAY += 0.1

def LEDseq():
    while True:
        for LED in LIGHTS:
            LED.on()
            sleep(DELAY)
            LED.off()
        for LED in reversed(LIGHTS):
            LED.on()
            sleep(DELAY)
            LED.off()


try:
    signal(SIGTERM, cleanup)
    pushButton.when_pressed = incrementDelay
    LEDseq()
    pause()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit(1)
```